# Java Eclipse source tree void message

Tags: java, eclipse

Am getting exception when trying to run a Java program. When I look at source in Eclipse - `main(String[])` is `void` the code there is: can you point me in right direction, what is missing, is it simple missing or we need to build a class?

here is the TTPublic class

```
package orderimport.com.ca.ttorders;

import net.ibs.framework.*;
import net.ibs.framework.db.*;
import net.ibs.framework.lang.*;
import net.ibs.framework.log.IBSEnvironmentLog;
import net.ibs.integrator.base.*;
import net.ibs.framework.util.*;
import net.ibs.framework.asw.*;
import net.ibs.framework.db.Query;
public class TTProcessOrders{
    public TTProcessOrders(){
    }


    public IASWConnection ASW = null;
    public String templateAndParmList = " ";

    public String FWD_SLASH = "\\";
    public String fileName = " ";
    public String saveFile = " ";

    public String apos = "'";
    public StringCollection parameters = new StringCollection("",",",false);
    public String param = "'";
    public String holdYESNO = "NO";
    public String warehouse = " ";
    public String addresscode = " ";
    public int IRO = 0;
    public String IROcustomer = " ";
    public String handler = " ";
    public String multipleSOtype = " ";
    public String singleSOtype = " ";
    // *IH Added Begin*
    public String shipViaOverride = " ";
    public int checkItemID = 0;
    // *IH Added End*


    // Begin 10/07/12 7:00 pm LUIS - Handle error alerts
    public String regularErrorRecipients = " ";
    public String ITerrorRecipients = " ";
    public String saveFolder = " ";
    public TTDataHandler util = null;
    public String import_id = " ";
    public String errorMessage = " ";

    public TTMapOrderData map = null;

public static void main(String[] args){
        IBSEnvironment.setBasePath("C:\\Integrator_DesignStudio\\bin");
        IBSEnvironmentLog.initialize("Default");
        TTProcessOrders obj = new TTProcessOrders();
        obj.main();
    }

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Date.getMillisOf(Date.java:939)
    at java.util.Date.compareTo(Date.java:959)
    at ordersimport.com.ca.ttorders.TTControlHandler.loadConfig(TTControlHandler.java:65)
    at ordersimport.com.ca.ttorders.TTControlHandler.getConfigProperty(TTControlHandler.java:109)
    at ordersimport.com.ca.ttorders.TTControlHandler.getASWVersion(TTControlHandler.java:133)
    at ordersimport.com.ca.ttorders.TTControlHandler.getASWConnection(TTControlHandler.java:265)
    at ordersimport.com.ca.ttorders.TTControlHandler.openSharedASWConnection(TTControlHandler.java:242)
    at ordersimport.com.ca.ttorders.TTProcessOrders.main(TTProcessOrders.java:86)
    at ordersimport.com.ca.ttorders.TTProcessOrders.main(TTProcessOrders.java:59)
```

Comment: show us the `TTProcessOrders` class, in specific the `main` method of that class (not the `main` of your program you wrote)

Comment: The log is so explicit, your code launches an error: 
"at ordersimport.com.ca.ttorders.TTControlHandler.loadConfig(TTControlHandler.java:65)" means that at your class TTControlHandler, at method loadConfig, at line 65, there's a problem. 
The problem is a java.lang.NullPointerException caused by a comparation between to attributes of Date type in which one of them is null. For further information we would need the definition of TTControlHandler class but I believe that it's not necessary and, with a simple debug, you will succeed in solve it